# How to group and sum by date xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

The XML below is generated from a query which selects all the report data whose lies between the  and the first of the date month. The MP for each , the id of which is , needs to be summed by request date, MP heading, and by month to date, MP MTD heading. This goes as well for the GroupName(LOID), and Listname(has no id, group by name).

The query data is non normalized. There is a one to many relationship between each ReportName and GroupName.  Likewise there is a one to many relationship between each GroupName and ListName. The xslt's job is to group each report, give the name of each report under the Row Labels, and give the MP summary by request date, and MP MTD by all dates. Under the ReportName begins a list of GroupNames directly underneath in the same column. Each GroupName will have  the associated ListNames listed directly underneath each GroupName. Again listed all in the same column. Each GroupName will have its MP and MP MTD calculated in the next two columns as will each ListName directly below. The totals for each GroupName MP's should equal the sums of its ListNames, and likewise each ReportName's total should be equal to the total of all associated GroupNames.

I have tried to be thorough in the above explanation. Please let me know if there is something anyone doesn't understand.

```
 <DocumentElement>  
        <MPReport>    

                <ReportDate>2014-09-02</ReportDate>
                <RequestDate>2014-09-03</RequestDate>
                <ReportName>Report1</ReportName>    
                <ReportID>3728</ReportID>   
                 <LOBMasterID>8466</LOBMasterID>            
                 <GroupName>Groupname1</GroupName>  
                    <ListName>ListName1</ListName>           
                 <MP>4</MP>  
             </MPReport>  
             <MPReport>    

                    <ReportDate>2014-09-03</ReportDate>
                    <RequestDate>2014-09-03</RequestDate>
                  <ReportName>Report1</ReportName>   
                 <ReportID>3728</ReportID> 
                 <LOID>8466</LOID>  
                 <GroupName>Groupname1</GroupName> 
                 <ListName>ListName2</ListName> 
                 <MP>3</MP> 
             </MPReport>         
                     <MPReport>    

        <ReportDate>2014-09-02</ReportDate>      
    <RequestDate>2014-09-03</RequestDate>       
                <ReportName>Report1</ReportName>    
                <ReportID>3728</ReportID>   
                 <LOID>8467</LOID>    
                 <GroupName>Groupname2</GroupName>    
                 <ListName>ListName3</ListName> 
                 <MP>2</MP>  
             </MPReport>  
             <MPReport>    

                    <ReportDate>2014-09-03</ReportDate>             
                 <RequestDate>2014-09-03</RequestDate>
                  <ReportName>Report1</ReportName>   
                 <ReportID>3728</ReportID> 
                 <LOID>8467</LOID>  
                 <GroupName>Groupname2</GroupName> 
                 <ListName>ListName4</ListName> 
                 <MP>3</MP> 
             </MPReport>         
             <MPReport>  

                 <ReportDate>2014-09-01</ReportDate>    
                 <RequestDate>2014-09-03</RequestDate>
                 <ReportName>Report1</ReportName> 
                 <ReportID>3729</ReportID>  
                 <LOID>8538</LOID>   
                 <GroupName>Groupname3</GroupName>
                     <ListName>ListName5</ListName> 
                 <MP>3</MP> 
             </MPReport> 
    <MPReport>  

                 <ReportDate>2014-09-03</ReportDate>    
                 <RequestDate>2014-09-03</RequestDate>
                 <ReportName>Report1</ReportName> 
                 <ReportID>3729</ReportID>  
                 <LOID>8538</LOID>   
                 <GroupName>Groupname3</GroupName>
                     <ListName>ListName6</ListName> 
                 <MP>3</MP> 
             </MPReport>         
     </DocumentElement>

     <html>
     <head></head>

     <body>
     <table>
     <tr>
     <th>Row Labels</th>
     <th>MP</th>
     <th>MP MTD</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Report1</td>
     <td>9</td>
     <td>20</>
     <td></td>
     <tr>
     <td>Groupname1</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>7</td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>ListName1</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>4</td> 
     </tr>
      <tr>
     <td>ListName2</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>3</td> 
     </tr>


     <tr>
     <td>Groupname2</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>7</td> 
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td>ListName3</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td> 
     </tr>
      <tr>
     <td>ListName4</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>3</td> 
     </tr>

    <td>Groupname3</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>6</td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>ListName5</td>
     <td>0</td>
     <td>3</td> 
     </tr>
      <tr>
     <td>ListName6</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>3</td> 
     </tr>


     </table>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a better explanation of the logic behind the required transformation? I see a RequestDate, but it's the same for all MPReports - so grouping by it is meaningless; I don't see anything that looks like a "*month to date(MP MTD column).*" -- In any case, for grouping in XSLT 1.0 you will want to start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: I've since edited the question. Hopefully its more clear now.

Comment: No, I am afraid it's not. I suggest you describe the process step-by-step - as if explaining it to someone who has to do it manually.

Comment: I rewrote the question and tried to explain things step by step this time. Sorry, it's taken two times.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is still not only too difficult to understand - it is also *way* too much to ask within the confines of a SO question, let alone a single one.

In an effort to move this forward, I suggest you study the following stylesheet:

XSLT **1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="report-by-groupID" match="MPReport" use="LOID" />
<xsl:key name="report-by-groupName" match="MPReport" use="GroupName" />

<xsl:template match="/DocumentElement">
    <table border="1">
        <!-- HEADER -->
        <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>MP</th>
            <th>MP TD</th> 
        </tr>
        <!-- MASTER REPORT -->
        <tr>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="MPReport[LOBMasterID]/ReportName"/></th>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="sum(MPReport/MP)"/></th>
            <th>???</th> 
        </tr>
        <!-- FOR EACH DISTINCT GROUP -->
        <xsl:for-each select="MPReport[not(LOBMasterID)][count(. | key('report-by-groupID', LOID)[1]) = 1]">
            <tr>
                <th><xsl:value-of select="GroupName"/></th>
                <th><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('report-by-groupName', GroupName)/MP)"/></th>
                <th>??</th> 
            </tr>
            <!-- FOR EACH LIST IN THIS GROUP -->
            <xsl:for-each select="key('report-by-groupName', GroupName)">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="ListName"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="MP"/></td>
                    <td>?</td> 
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It outputs:

1. A single row for the **master** report (identified by having a `LOBMasterID`
   node);
2. A row for each distinct **group** of reports, grouped by the `LOID`
   value;
3. A row for each **report** (`ListName`) in the group, linked to the
   current group by the `GroupName` value;

I have calculated a subtotal of the `MP` values for each group, as well as a grand total at the master report level; **these numbers do NOT match the numbers you show in your expected output**.

I have no idea what is supposed to go into the `MP TD` column.

Applied to your input example, the rendered result looks like this:

[image]